# Export map from QGIS and import in Locus map (Android)

Tags: qgis

I'm looking for a way to save a map from QGIS and import it into Locus Map, an Android app.

Specifically, I want to use the map provided at https://basemap.de/viewer/ in exactly the same way it's shown there.

The map material is offered as a vector tile service described at https://basemap.de/web-vektor/, more specifically the vector tiles are at https: //sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_de_3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf with these style definitions https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/styles/bm_web_top.json

I'm a complete newbie in QGIS but found this tutorial (German, but I'm sure you can easily spot the relevant info) https://geoobserver.wordpress.com/2022/08/10/qgis-tipp-basemap-de-als-vectortiles/ to do the above and also export using the qtiles Plugin.

However, when using qtiles to export into the mbfiles format, it seems there is no progress at all. The bar doesn't move. Note that I selected entire Germany in all zoom levels, so I'm suspecting this to be quite some amount of data. But I'm wondering whether this is expected of qtiles or whether I did something wrong in the process?